# HTML Import not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, polymer

According to this [article](http://robdodson.me/blog/2013/08/20/exploring-html-imports/),
it is possible to use HTML Imports via Polymer on browsers other than the latest version of Chrome (which might be the only one enabling HTML Imports at the moment). However, with the following html, adapted from the same article:

**1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic HTML Imports</title>
    <!-- Pull in our blog post example -->
    <link rel="import" href="2.html">

  </head>
<body>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
<script src="platform.js"></script>
<script>
      window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', function() {
        var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
        var content = link.import.querySelector('#test');
        document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2.html**

```
<div id="test">
  <h1>Here is the Import </h1>
</div>
```

I am getting the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi5Dp.png).

It appears that the `<div id="test">` is imported successfully in Firefox but not in Chrome. Note that I tried to enable experimental Web Platform features in about:flags.

Is there any way to make it work for Chrome as well? I am looking for any solution that would enable me to use basic imports with the latest build of both Firefox and Chrome. (My project won't go live until early 2016, so I am hoping that standard support will be provided across every platform by then, but a workaround would be great in the meantime.) Thanks.

Comment: this is how they have it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#link-type-import

Comment: Hmm forgive me for my comment then as I usually use PHP for this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you were using `file:` protocol, which is blocked by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

[W3C spec on HTML Imports](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#fetching-import):

> All imports linked from documents that is the master document or the one in the import map must be loaded using **potentially CORS-enabled fetch** with mode set to "Anonymous".

You could try to run a server on localhost, that would help.

Comment: Just checked - it works online indeed. All I used was href="2.html", how come that doesn't work locally? The files are all in the same folder.

Comment: On this point, Chrome has different policy with Firefox. I don't know the specific rationale but generally it is security concern. Likewise, you can't request resources via XMLHttpRequest if you don't have a server.

Comment: one more clarification: what should the syntax be, then, if I want the import to execute correctly offline in Chrome? the fact that href="2.html" works just fine when linking to another page but fails in the import case doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: No you can't. You must have a server. This is due to the browser's security policy. `href` works on `<a>` doesn't necessarily mean it also works on other tags, with `file://` protocol. Take a look at [**this article**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#started), it says **The URL of an import is called an import location. To load content from another domain, the import location needs to be CORS-enabled**.

Comment: More on [W3C spec on HTML Imports](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#fetching-import). **All imports linked from documents that is the master document or the one in the import map must be loaded using _potentially CORS-enabled fetch_ with mode set to "Anonymous".**