# How to run Polymer locally, without any web server?

Tags: polymer

I have designed the UI for a desktop app using Polymer. However When I run the app locally it gives me the following error : *"Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."* 
As it is a desktop app I need no internet connectivity and no web server. Any solution to run this app locally ? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Import not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222306/html-import-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: In short: no, you need a web server, even if a local one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import`s cannot work without a web server because it potentially violates some of browser's security policies and I am sure you know that.

#### Here are a few solutions:

- Use a local web-server with python or Node to serve the Custom-elements
- If you use `node-webkit` to wrap your `HTML`, it comes with a built-in server so no worries about any web-server

P.S. Using a web-server is always a safer choice.

Comment: To run a local simple python server `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: Now one can use `polymer serve`, as well, but just for local testing. For a desktop app written in polymer, you would definitely want to bundle the node-webkit server or some other modern variation.

Answer (score 1):

You can open in your browser a local HTML file which uses Polymer, and this without running a localhost server. But as Adi mentionned, **you won't be able to import local HTML files**. That's why you should declare your Polymer element in the same file as the body of your page.

Here's a simple Hello Polymer element in 1 file (importing Polymer library from the Poligit server, not local). You can save this file localy, and execute it in your browser, it should work without any executing local server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Polymer 2 -->
    <script src="https://polygit.org/webcomponentsjs+1.0.0-rc.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="import"  href="https://polygit.org/polymer+2.0.0-rc.2/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

    
</head>


<!-- Body -->
  <body>
  <!-- Hello element definition -->
    <dom-module id="hello-element">
     <template>
      <span>Hello {{name}}!</span>
     </template>

     <script>
      class HelloElement extends Polymer.Element {
       static get is(){
        return "hello-element";
       }

       static get properties() {
        return {
         name : {
          type : String,
          value : "world"
         }
        }
       }
      }
      customElements.define(HelloElement.is, HelloElement);
     </script>
    </dom-module>

    <!-- Element instance -->
    <hello-element></hello-element>
    <p/>
    <hello-element name="Hammy"></hello-element>
  </body>

</html>
```