# HTML5 Importing external local html file in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cors

Earlier I somehow managed to load html code from external html file from my index.html using

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="html/html_snippets.html">
</head>
```

and then find it with

```
var mySnippet = $(".foo").html();
```

but now I started to receive errors about CORS policy:

```
Access to Imported resource at 'file:///path/html/html_snippets.html' from origin 'file://' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

and I can't make it work.

How can I override this, I need to have html snippets in external file and load them just once at startup, and work on them later.

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222306/html-import-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: thisn question and answer don't help me, I need to have the file locally, and don't want to use external libraries for everything...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, HTML have option to include the html file . The syntax is like

```
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>
```

For reference  http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: this seems to be working, but I really don't want to use yet another external script for something that should be simple