# Imported HTML doesn't show up

Tags: html, import

I used

```
<link rel="import" href="login.html">
```

To import html from another page into a popped out modal. It leaves the pop out completely blank.

I found various different ways to import html but when they DO work the .css is erased as well as the buttons. Is import just not made for modals?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773925/6127393

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import HTML document using HTML link rel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612405/import-html-document-using-html-link-rel)